# Using STUFF to GROUP BY something

Tags: sql

Trying to order by the [Booking Date]. The output looks like **1111 | Adelaide; Brisbane | 4000; 5000** but the postcode for **Adelaide = 5000 and Brisbane = 4000**. This will cause some confusion for the users. The error im getting is **ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified**.

---

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#locations') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #locations

select distinct([Case ID]), [Booking City], [Booking Postcode]
into #locations
from ETL_Operations
where cast([Booking Date] as date) between '2019-07-01' and '2019-09-30'

SELECT DISTINCT
    [Case ID], -- primary key

    [Service] =
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '; ' + [Booking City]
        FROM #locations b -- input table
        WHERE (b.[Case ID] = a.[Case ID]) -- primary key
        order by [Booking City]
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''),

    [Topic] =
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '; ' + [Booking Postcode]
        FROM #locations b -- input table
        WHERE (b.[Case ID] = a.[Case ID]) -- primary key
        order by [Booking Date]
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')

FROM #locations a -- input table
GROUP BY [Case ID] -- primary key
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is very close , just remove the order by

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    [Case ID], -- primary key
    [Service] = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '; ' + [Booking City]
                FROM #locations b -- input table
                WHERE (b.[Case ID] = a.[Case ID]) -- primary key
                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''),

    [Topic] = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '; ' + [Booking Postcode]
                FROM #locations b -- input table
                WHERE (b.[Case ID] = a.[Case ID]) -- primary key
                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
 FROM #locations a -- input table
 GROUP BY [Case ID] -- primary key
```

Comment: I think I was miss understood. If I don’t have an order by, it will print like (Adelaide, Brisbane) then (4000, 5000). As I said above, it should read as (Adelaide, Brisbane) then (5000,4000) because Adelaide relates to 5000 and Brisbane relates to 4000. But SQL prints A to Z